# Is a Guava Table thread safe when its backing maps are thread safe?

Tags: java, guava

Will Guava's [Tables.newCustomTable(Map, Supplier)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#newCustomTable-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) method return thread safe tables when supplied with thread safe maps?  For example:

```
public static <R, C, V> Table<R, C, V> newConcurrentTable() {
  return Tables.newCustomTable(
      new ConcurrentHashMap<R, Map<C, V>>(),
      new Supplier<Map<C, V>>() {
        public Map<C, V> get() {
          return new ConcurrentHashMap<C, V>();
        }
      });
}
```

Does that code actually return concurrent tables?

Comment: What's your definition of "concurrent tables?"

Comment: Good question. To phrase my question another way: Will those tables blow up in ways that a ConcurrentMap<R, ConcurrentMap<C, V>> would not?  And by "blow up" I mean get into infinite loops, throw exceptions, or do whatever else a regular HashBasedTable would do if you tried to read from and write to it on multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the doc: "If multiple threads access this table concurrently and one of the threads modifies the table, it must be synchronized externally."

Concurrent backing collections aren't enough.

Comment: Oddly enough, that sentence in the javadoc is what prompted me to ask this question. Oh well. Thanks, Kevin.

Answer (score 19):

Kevin Bourrillion is right. The technical reason for the map you've constructed not to be thread safe is that even if the maps you are using are thread safe, the table operations may not be. Let me give an example of put, as implemented in the `StandardTable`, which is used by `Tables.newCustomTable`:

```
public V put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
  Map<C, V> map = backingMap.get(rowKey);
  if (map == null) {
    map = factory.get();
    backingMap.put(rowKey, map);
  }
  return map.put(columnKey, value);
}
```

Thread safety is compromised in the handling of the `map == null` case. Namely, two or more threads could enter that block and create a new entry for the `columnKey` and the last one to perform a `backingMap.put(rowKey, map)` would ultimately override the entry for the `columnKey` in the `backingMap`, which would lead to the loss of `put` operations performed by other threads. In particular the result of this operation in a multithreaded environment is non-deterministic, which is equivalent to saying that this operation is not thread safe.

The correct implementation of this method would be:

```
public V put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
    ConcurrentMap<C, V> map = table.get(rowKey);
    if (map == null) {
        backingMap.putIfAbsent(rowKey, factory.get());
    }
    map = backingMap.get(rowKey);
    return map.put(columnKey, value);
}
```

I'm currently investigating if it is possible to use the `ForwardingTable` implementation together with what you've wanted to do, to get a properly thread safe `ConcurrentTable`.

But to be honest, I think the reason there is no thread-safe implementation of the `Table` is that the interface itself doesn't provide any concurrency constructs, such as `putIfAbsent` or `replace`.

Comment: After having had an extensive browse through the `StandardTable` implementation I came to a conclusion that in order to provide thread safety you have only two choices: create an implementation from scratch, or provide a wrapper that locks on every access. The reason for it being that the views returned by the row(), column() or the columnMap() are not thread safe, and there is no way to modify their behaviour through method overrides.

Comment: For the restricted case where you know that multiple threads will never do anything other than put on different row keys, this _seems_ like it should be safe?  The context is that I want to build up a Table using parallel threads.