# how to achieve cell level lock in guava table

Tags: concurrency, locking, guava

I am using guava table as in memory cache. I want do not want to lock the whole table for update rather want to lock only that cell.

```
private Table<String, String, State> cache = HashBasedTable.create();

 public void updateStateCache(String switchOid, String entityOid, State state) {
        synchronized ((switchOid+entityOid).intern()) {
            this.cche.put(switchOid, entityOid, state);
        }
    }
```

- will it guarantee cell level lock or I have to lock the whole table
  while updating?
- is this the right way to do as `string.itern()` is not recommended?

Comment: You probably _will_ have to lock the whole table, as the locking within the data structure doesn't work that way -- it wouldn't work, for example, to lock one entry of a `HashMap`, you have to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Hiccup, What did u finally do ? I have similar requirement where I would like to lock row wise.will synchronized (switchOid).intern()) { } work ?

Comment: no. used Striped lock to achieve cell level locking.     Striped<ReadWriteLock> stripedRWLocks; public void updateStateCache(NfcOid switchOid, NfcOid entityOid, StateInfo stateInfo) {
        Lock writeLock = acquireWriteLock(entityOid.getOid());
        try {
            writeLock.lock();
            stateInfoCache.put(switchOid, entityOid, stateInfo);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Map<C, V> getOrCreate(R rowKey) {
    Map<C, V> map = backingMap.get(rowKey);
    if (map == null) {
      map = factory.get();
      backingMap.put(rowKey, map);
    }
    return map;
  }
  @CanIgnoreReturnValue
  @Override
  public V put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value) {
    checkNotNull(rowKey);
    checkNotNull(columnKey);
    checkNotNull(value);
    return getOrCreate(rowKey).put(columnKey, value);
  }
```

Thread safety is compromised in the handling of the map == null case. Namely, two or more threads [ example (switch1 + interface1) and (switch1 + interface2) if we use (switOid+enityOid).intern() to synchronise ] in same time. could enter that block and create a new entry for the columnKey and the last one to perform a backingMap.put(rowKey, map) would ultimately override the entry for the columnKey in the backingMap, which would lead to the loss of put operations performed by other threads. In particular the result of this operation in a multithreaded environment is non-deterministic, which is equivalent to saying that this operation is not thread safe

[Is a Guava Table thread safe when its backing maps are thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018135/is-a-guava-table-thread-safe-when-its-backing-maps-are-thread-safe)